# How to solve: Scalar subquery produced more than one element

Tags: google-bigquery

I have following query. In cte_2, I'm using result from cte_1. It gives me an error:Scalar subquery produced more than one element. How to solve it.

```
WITH cte_1 AS

(SELECT a,b,c FROM t1)


,cte_2 AS
 (SELECT
 ,(select a from cte_1) as a    
 ,d as fix  
 ,d.*
 FROM t2 AS cr
 LEFT JOIN t3 AS d
        ON cr.Date = d.Date)

 Select * from cte_2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> error:Scalar subquery produced more than one element. How to solve it?

Instead of `(select a from cte_1)` - use `ARRAY(select a from cte_1)`

Comment: Hi Mikhali, Looks like it takes longer time to run.

Comment: I answered the issue you asked in your original question. If you have more / new questions - post new question

Comment: Hi Mikhali, it is the same question. I use ARRAY(select a from cte_1) instead of (select a from cte_1), it takes longer time. I'm running it now. Already 20 mins over, still running.

Comment: Hi Mikhali, I have another question. Can you please look into this.https://stackoverflow.com/q/63422937/13743270

Comment: Hi Mikhali, Can you please help me  into this. stackoverflow.com/q/63422937/13743270